# Succinct way of saying "Related to Take a Byte"

Tags: phrase-requests

I have a website with many RSS feeds (http://www.sonihal.com/rss-feeds.html) that include

1 - My blog entries

2 - Articles that relate to the blog's subject area

For instance, the website has a blog related to information technology (I call it "Take a Byte")

But I also created another RSS feed from several information technology websites, and I called it "Related to Take a Byte", but I find this name too long.

What is a succinct, yet descriptive name for this type of blog to let the user know this RSS feed is related to articles that are posted under "Take a Byte".

In other words, I would like "Take a Byte" to be included in the RSS feed hyperlink.

Thanks!

I using "Take a Byte" as an example. Am looking to apply the same word format to other RSS feeds from Internet that is similar to my content.

Comment: "Related: [Take a Byte](http://www.sonihal.com/rss-feeds.html)"

Comment: Call it "Bake a Tyte".

Comment: @anemone That's actually interesting .... May consider .......

Comment: What's with the downvote?

Comment: It would seem, Sonihal, that there are among us, those unable to resist *the power of the mouse* to inflict anonymous and petty insult. Find solace in the knowledge that their power to injure is restricted to mouse-clicks and not WMDs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

re**BYTE** or **Take a Byte II** or **Take-2-Bytes** or **TAKE2BYTES**

Comment: I decided to add II to the end

Answer (score 2):

May I suggest: **Take a Byte** **+**, OR **Take a Byte Plus** Or **Web Take a Byte**

Comment: **bold** your *+sign* so it appears attached to your 1st suggestion.